# How to get exact NTP drift in OS X

Tags: macos, ntp

I'm trying to get actual NTP drift on Macs connected to a local NTP server.

- When reading `/var/db/ntp.drift` file I get -37.521 which according to [PPM to milliseconds conversion](https://pthree.org/2013/10/13/ntp-drift-file/) gives **-3241ms** of drift.
- When using `ntpq -c lpeer` I get something like this:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*172-1-1-5.light 164.67.62.212    2 u   57   64  377  199.438   38.322  29.012
```

which gives me offset of **38.322ms**

- Finally, `sntp 172.1.1.5` outpus this:

```
2016 Jan 21 18:41:45.248591 +0.019244 +/- 0.022507 secs
```

which says having about **19ms** of drift.

I'm confused which one the approaches gives accurate NTP drift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sntp gives the current offset. The ntp.drift file is updated only occasionally, I think when the daemon starts.